# R_squared vs epochs

Tags: python, tensorflow, machine-learning, keras, neural-network

Goodmorning, I'm a python beginner, I'm trying to build my first neural network. Is there a way to plot the R2 evolution vs epochs? I evaluate R2 in the following way: `r2_score(y_test_pred, y_test)`. I have built a fully connected neural network in this way:

```
optimizer = tf.keras.optimizers.Adam(lr=0.001)
model = Sequential()

# ,kernel_regularizer=l2(c), bias_regularizer=l2(c)
model.add(Dense(100, input_shape = (X_train.shape[1],), activation = 'relu',kernel_initializer='glorot_uniform'))
model.add(Dropout(0.2))
model.add(Dense(100, activation = 'relu',kernel_initializer='glorot_uniform'))
model.add(Dropout(0.2))
model.add(Dense(100, activation = 'relu',kernel_initializer='glorot_uniform'))

model.add(Dense(1,activation = 'linear',kernel_initializer='glorot_uniform'))

model.compile(loss = 'mse', optimizer = optimizer, metrics = ['mse'])

history = model.fit(X_train, y_train, epochs = 100,
                    validation_split = 0.1, shuffle=False, batch_size=250
                    )

history_dict = history.history
`
```

the dataset is composed by 18 features and 1 label, it is a regression task.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You just have to add it on your `compile` line.

```py
model.compile(loss = 'mse', optimizer = optimizer, metrics = ['mse', r2_score])
```

If you want to do that you need to create a metric that can be understood by keras,

```py
import tf.keras.backend as K

def r2_score(y_true, y_pred):
    SS_res =  K.sum(K.square(y_true - y_pred)) 
    SS_tot = K.sum(K.square(y_true - K.mean(y_true))) 
    return ( 1 - SS_res/(SS_tot + K.epsilon()) )
```

The code is taken from [kaggle](https://www.kaggle.com/c/mercedes-benz-greener-manufacturing/discussion/34019)

Sorry I forgot to add the Tensorboard part.

If you want to see the evolution of loss/metrics during training you can use Tensorboard, as in [the doc](https://www.tensorflow.org/tensorboard/scalars_and_keras)

```py
logdir = "logs/" + datetime.now().strftime("%Y%m%d-%H%M%S")
tensorboard_callback = tf.keras.callbacks.TensorBoard(log_dir=logdir)


history = model.fit(X_train, y_train, epochs = 100,
                    validation_split = 0.1, shuffle=False, batch_size=250, calllbacks=[tensorboard_callback])
```

And then access Tensorboard using this line in a terminal

`tensorboard --logdir logs`

You can then access tensorboard on your browser by going at `localhost:6006`

Comment: thanks for the answer, I have tried to implement this in my code but it gives me this erreor: TypeError: Expected sequence or array-like, got <class 'tensorflow.python.framework.ops.Tensor'>.  What can I do?

Comment: You used the one using keras backend or your own r2_score? I guess your r2_score function use numpy arrays right?

Comment: I substitute in my code this line: model.compile(loss = 'mse', optimizer = optimizer, metrics = ['mse', r2_score]). And the I add the part of tensorboard. But the error is still present. Then I don't understand how should I implement this line "tensorboard --logdir logs"

Comment: The error you're getting is because your r2_score is using arrays and not tensors.You need to use the `r2_keras` function I posted, or change your r2_score so that it can use tensors (with keras backend)

Comment: `tensorboard --logdir logs` is to be launched from a terminal, you'll then access tensorboard by going in your browser and typing localhost:6006 in the url bar

Comment: I try to run the code without the callbacks, and it works. Unfortunatly, I don't know why, with callbacks it doesn't work.

Comment: this is the error: AttributeError: 'TensorBoard' object has no attribute 'on_train_batch_begin'. Do you know how can I avoid it?

Comment: You're probably using keras and tf.keras in the same file. Use only tf.keras or keras. If you use both there are some mess in the imports